# Retrieve values from string using javascript. ( String is piece of HTML )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a C# developer. My clientside javascript skills are very low.

In javascript I have a string value. That contains the following:

```
<div id="foo" data-redirectURL="bar">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**How do I retrieve the value of `data-redirectURL` in this case: "bar" ?**

Comment: Everyone who's answer this question, please notice that he said the HTML is in a **string**, not in the DOM.

Comment: Please show us the code in relevant context.

Comment: @Barmar Why did you delete your answer.

Comment: @Kinduser It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attr` like this:

```js
var str = '<div id="foo" data-redirectURL="bar"><div>Lorem Ipsum</div></div>';

var value = $(str).attr("data-redirectURL");

console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tested this code and it worked. So I accept this as the answer!

Comment: You took the effort to read my question. And provided the most simple and readable answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust your data attribute and use `data()` :

```
$('#foo').data('redirect-url');
```

HTML :

```
<div id="foo" data-redirect-url="bar">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

**DOM snippet :**

```js
console.log( $('#foo').data('redirect-url') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo" data-redirect-url="bar">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**String snippet :**

```js
var my_string = '<div id="foo" data-redirect-url="bar"><div>Lorem Ipsum</div></div>';

console.log( $(my_string).data('redirect-url') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _I have a string value_, he said!

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways of getting a data attribute value on

jquery: `$('#foo').attr("data-redirectURL")`

javascript: `document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('data-redirectURL');`

```js
console.log($('#foo').attr("data-redirectURL"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" data-redirectURL="bar">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: with jquery you can just use `$('#foo').data("redirectURL")`

Comment: This searches the DOM, not a string.

Comment: @SteevePitis : please consider the fact that the HTML is a string ! It is not part of the DOM!

Comment: _I have a string value_, he said!